# IOS Switch view and storyboard not works

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, nslog

I have a problem with switching views. I'm using a simulator with xcode 4.2

Storyboard contains:

- `NavigationController` (initial view controller)
- `UIViewController` which has relationship with the navigation controller
- `UIViewController` (paired with my custom class: `ViewEntryImageController`) which hasn't got any relationship. Contains a button, a bottom toolbar with some toolbar button.

User come into the `UIViewController`, where he can see a `ScrollView` and in `ScrollView` some images.

Images has a gesture:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openEntryImage)];
    [image addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
```

The openEntryImage function:

```
(IBAction)openEntryImage
{
    ViewEntryImageController *controller=[[ViewEntryImageController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

When I try to tap the image, the `openEntryImage` works as well (the effect is correct), but I don't see my `ViewEntryImageController` view and my buttons, I'm only see a black window.

I try to put a **NSLog** line into the `ViewEntryImageController` `viewDidLoad` function, and it works, so what is the black window and where is my view controller?

When I try to use `pushViewController`, on the new view I found a navigation toolbar with a back button, but no other controls.

I tried another version, I created a `UIViewController` class, but now with a **xib** file. I used it instead of `ViewEntryImageController` and it works. Why?
I want to use this controller in storyboard too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
ViewEntryImageController *controller=[[ViewEntryImageController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewEntryImageController" bundle:nil];
```

If you don't use .nib names but rather use storyboards, it's a bit harder. Create a segue from the controller to the ViewEntryImageController controller by holding ctrl and dragging from one view to the other. Click this segue and give it an identifier.

Then use the `[self performSegue:@"identifier"];` function to present the next view.

Answer (score 4):

The `ViewEntryImageController` class by itself has no information about how to build the dialog. But you can instantiate your view controller on your own from the storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardFileName" bundle:nil];
ViewEntryImageController *controller = (ViewEntryImageController *)[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewEntryImage"];
```

This assumes a storyboard name of `StoryboardFileName` and that the view entry image controller has an identifier of `ViewEntryImage` set in the view properties (Attributes inspector, section "View Controller").

Comment: Would be great to accept the answer or at least vote if it did work ;-) (You can accept only one answer per question)

Comment: Yes I know. Your answer is great, but the previous is shorter and I love shorted codes :) I tried to vote up but I can't yet, because: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation", so sorry, and many thanks again.
When I get this, I come back and vote up :)

Comment: Oh I see, no problem then :-)

Comment: +1 Wow! That solved my protracted battle with the issue! :) Thanks!